# Magento, distincts search results per store

Tags: php, magento, search, view, store

my site have this structure:

Website -> 2 stores -> 3 views per store

I want to get distinct search results per store, for example:

Store 1 have Category root "Clothing" with there respective products.
Store 2 have Category root "Electronics" with there respective products.

I need to show only the products assigned to the root category(or children categories) on the search results of the respective Store.

Any Idea ? 
THANKS!